# Can't deploy Qt application with QMYSQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have an application that requires to connect to MySQL database, I am using Qt 4.7. I built the QMYSQL plugin and everything works just fine ON MY MACHINE. When I tried to test the application on another machine *with the folder "sqldrivers" contains the "qsqlmysql4.dll" next to my executable*. I get this error "**Driver not loaded**". After hours of searching the web and following the Qt documentation I came up with nothing.
Please tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an actual mysql client DLL (like `libmysqlclient.dll` or something) that's installed on your machine, and also needs to be included with the app?

Comment: Exactly, Thank you @Brendan. This is what was missing. I added libmysql.dll which is in the MySQL bin folder and it worked. Thanks again